# $X$ exponential random variable - probability

Tags: probability

We know that $X$ is an exponential random variable with parameter $\gamma$.

I need to calculate $\mathbb{E}[X|X>1]$.

How I do it?

Comment: **Hint** For an even $A$, you have that $\mathbb E[X\mid A]=\frac{\mathbb E[X\boldsymbol 1_A]}{\mathbb P(A)}.$

Comment: is it true -       E[X|X>1]=eθe−θx=eθ(1−x) ?

Comment: [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conditonal density is

$$f_{X|X>1}=e^{\theta}\theta e^{-\theta x}=\theta e^{\theta(1-x)}$$

To calculate the conditional expectation you get

$$E(X|X>1)=\int_1^{\infty}x\theta e^{\theta(1-x)}dx=1+\frac{1}{\theta}$$

---

But you can calculate your expectation quickly using memoryless property

$$E(X|X>1)=1+E(X)=1+\frac{1}{\theta}$$

Comment: can you explain it to me?

Comment: @user123 $$f_{X|X>A}=\frac{1}{1-F_X(A)}f_X(x)$$

Comment: thank you, but I think I don't succeeded to understand the whole calculate. is it not conditional exepcation?

Comment: @user123 ups sorry...yes.... I gave you the conditional density...now I think it is very easy for you to calculate your desired expectation....but there is obviously a quick way using memoryless property

Comment: ok now I get really confused. what you wrote it's not right? I need to to do E[x]/p(x) ?

Comment: @user123 : I have been a little cryptic and I had also a I got a little misunderstanding. Now my answer is complete and, I think, clear. If it has been useful you can mark it as accepted

Comment: thank you very much. now it's clear